# Expand menu extension in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

In a video I saw how to hide the code between 2 comments in a Powershell ps1 file, see picture:
[image]
The comment started on line 5 #region and ended on line 24 #endregion and between these lines code was shown to be executed. The presenter was able to show and hide all the code between these lines. Does anyone know how this works? Is there an extension for this?

The video can be seen
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LySy7rrUO8
from minute 4:50 you can see what I mean.

Comment: This functionality is built into editors like Visual Studio Code. Are you asking because you want to do this in an editor you are writing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability to expand/collapse comment-regions is supported in both Windows PowerShell ISE (`powershell_ise.exe`), and in [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with the [official PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell) installed - the latter is what the presenter is using in the video you linked.

Both editors will also let you expand/collapse logical blocks spanning multiple lines (scriptblocks, hashtable and array literals, operator expressions, etc.), even without `#region`/`#endregion` comments.

Comment: I found an extension:

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maptz.regionfolder

Comment: @SQLFRAGE Feel free to supply your own answer below